# Union of countable sets

Tags: functions

I have the set:
$$\Bbb N \cup \{(i, j) \in \Bbb N^2| i \le j\}$$
I don't really understand the meaning of $\Bbb N^2$.
I think I would have $\Bbb N \cup {(0,0), (0,1), ... (1,1), (1,2)...(n,n)}$
Which would be exactly $\Bbb N$ and the $\Bbb N^2$ would be useless. But I dont get why won't they just put $\Bbb N$ instead.

Comment: Please fix your notation.

Comment: $N^2$ is the set of pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a\in N$ and $b\in N$. Is this where your confusion is?

Comment: Your second-to-last sentence suggests that you think that e.g. $(4, 7)$ is a natural number - is this accurate?

Comment: $N^2$ is my confusion, i thought that it would be for any a $\in N$, a has to be $a^2$

Comment: conventionally, If $A$ is a set (maybe $\mathbb N$ or $\mathbb R$ but could be any set then $A^n = A\times A\times.....\times A = \{(a_1, a_2, ..., a_3)|a_i\in A\} = \{$ all $n$-tuples of $A\}$. And $\mathbb N^2$ is the set of all ordered pairs $\{(n,m)|n,m\in \mathbb N\}$.

Comment: I dont get what would N $\cup$ a set of pairs (a,b) would be

Comment: I'd be similar to $N \cup $ a set of elephants, would be be like.  All the natural numbers will be elements of the union.  And several elephants would would be in the union.  So this set would contain all the natural numbers, and it would contain all the ordered pairs where the first time is smaller than the second.  That numbers and ordered pairs have nothing to do with each other, doesn't matter.  The $\cup$ just means you dump everything together in a bag.

Answer (score 0):

For any set $S$, $S^2$ typically denotes $S\times S$, or in even more basic notation $\{\langle a, b\rangle\ | \ a\in S \land b\in S\}.$

In the case of your problem, $(i, j)\in\Bbb N^2$ and $i,j\in\Bbb N$ would be equivalent, however the first is less ambiguous.

The set $\Bbb N \cup \{(i, j) \in \Bbb N^2| i \le j\}$ is a set containing both 2d integer points and natural numbers.

Feel free to ask for further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A = \{$leafy green vegetables $\}$ and $B =\{$ characters from "The Game of Thrones"$\}$.

So $A \cup B = \{$ anything that is either a leafy green vegetable or a character from "The Game of Thrones"$\}$

$A \cup B = \{$ .... kale, lettuce, Ned Stark, bok choy, Tyrion Lanister, Pieter Littlefinger, cabbage....$\}$.

What do leafy green vegetables have to do with characters from the Game of Thrones?  Absolutely nothing.

You just took each of the two sets and dumped them together into a bag.

......

Now let $A = \mathbb N$.

And let $B = \{(j,k) \in \mathbb N\times \mathbb N| j \le k\}$.

So $A \cup B =  \mathbb N\cup \{(j,k) \in \mathbb N\times \mathbb N| j \le k\}$

$=\{...27, 15,(3,19), 14, (5, 129), (7, 31), 2, 348.....\}$

Would do individual numbers have to do with pairs of numbers where the first term is equal or less than the second?  Absolutely nothing (that I can tell.... or that I care about).

You just took each of the two sets and dumped them together into a bag.